I am new to gnome and I have no idea how to start it
I have installed GDM3 and I still cant figure out how to start up gnome

You've not provided any Ubuntu product & release details; so we've extremely limited details as to what you're using. GDM3 is a Display Manager and will act as greeter allowing you to login and start a session, be it GNOME or another you have installed. How gdm3 will operate though will depend on configuration & theme you're using; and you've provided no specifics for us to know how it'll work on your unknown system.

Ubuntu comes with GDM and Gnome preconfigured. Which OS are you using? Which version? What all customizations did you apply?
